# Mongoid Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have this model

```
  class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  has_one :user_details 

  field :email , type: String
  field :id_number , type: String
  field :crypted_password , type: String
  field :salt , type: String
  field :fname , type: String
  field :lname , type: String
  field :mname , type: String
end
```

And I want to add a relation to this model

```
class UserDetails
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user

  #fields
  field :year , type: String
  field :block , type: String
  field :course , type: String
  field :alumni , type: Boolean
end
```

but when I used it in my form it says Undefined Method 'year'
I tried to belongs_to :users, has_many :user_detail already still the same
this is in the view

```
 =f.text_field :year , placeholder: "Year"
```

**Log Error**

```
Started GET "/admin/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-16 20:15:32 +0800
```

Processing by Admin::UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered admin/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.haml (4.8ms)
  Rendered admin/app/views/admin/users/new.html.haml within layouts/admin/application (6.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `term' for #<User:0xa9f0a24>):
    66:       %section.col.col-3
    67:         %label.input
    68:           %i.icon-prepend.fa.fa-user
    69:           =f.text_field :term , placeholder: "Year"
    70:           %b.tooltip.tooltip-top-left
    71:             %i.fa.fa-warning.text-warning-teal Year
    72:       %section.col.col-3
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:28:in`value'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:37:in `value_before_type_cast'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in`block in render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in `fetch'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in`render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:771:in `text_field'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1258:in`text_field'
  admin/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.haml:69:in `block in _admin_app_views_admin_users__form_html_haml___623088800__625367368'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:132:in`call'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in form_for_with_haml'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:284:in`with_tabs'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:132:in `block in form_for_with_haml'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in`block in capture'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in`with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:47:in`capture_with_haml'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:134:in`form_for_with_haml'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:28:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
  admin/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.haml:1:in`_admin_app_views_admin_users__form_html_haml___623088800__625367368'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in`instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in`render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in`block in render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in`render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in`render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in`block in render_with_haml'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
  haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in`render_with_haml'
  admin/app/views/admin/users/new.html.haml:1:in `_admin_app_views_admin_users_new_html_haml___282327175__623578238'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in`block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in`instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in`block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in`block in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in`render_template'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in`render_template'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in`_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in`render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in`render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in`render'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`block in ms'
  /home/laziendo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`ms'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in`cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in`default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
  actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in`block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in`block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in`call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`method_missing'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in`call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/laziendo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
  /home/laziendo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/laziendo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in start_thread'

Rendered /home/laziendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/laziendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /home/laziendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (17.8ms)

Comment: I guess year is a "Defined Variable", So change the parameter name and try!!!

Comment: Still the same. I run rails console and run `User.new` but there's no such year,block,course,alumni fields

Comment: Did you changed parameter name "year"...!

Comment: yes I change it to `field :term , type: String`

Comment: Can you show me your log error?

Comment: Hey change "has_one :user_detail" not details

Comment: Ok I change `:user_details` to `:user_detail` still got the error.

Comment: Share your form template code, And one more thing class should be singular so change class name UserDetails to "UserDetail"

Comment: https://gist.github.com/silvercrow27/ad8cfc93e480a42df9fc

Comment: No you are totally doing wrong in form.. So please correct you class and check how to use accepts_nested_attributes_for for your app.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that User doesn't have a method named 'year', which it doesn't. UserDetails does. So you need to access year from UserDetails.

Comment: Then how can I do it using the relations in mongoid?